# Check point within polygon

Tags: c++, polygon

```
int pnpoly(int npol, float *xp, float *yp, float x, float y)
{
   int i, j, c = 0;
   for (i = 0, j = npol-1; i < npol; j = i++) {
     if ((((yp[i] <= y) && (y < yp[j])) ||
        ((yp[j] <= y) && (y < yp[i]))) &&
        (x < (xp[j] - xp[i]) * (y - yp[i]) / (yp[j] - yp[i]) + xp[i]))
       c = !c;
   }
   return c;
}
```

This function checks if a point is within a polygon. How do I deal with a polygon coordinate that is negative? For example,

```
float x[3] = { 0.16, 1.2, -10 };
float y[3] = { 1.8, 10, -5.5 };
```

I tried checking a valid point within the polygon and it returns 0.

Comment: What is your test point (for the given example)? This code and that example work just find for test points (-8.0, -4.0) and (0, 6).

Comment: exactly, negative coords seems not to be a problem here. do you understand how the algorithm works?

Comment: float x[3] = { -10, 0.17, 10 };                                 float y[3] = { -5.56, 1.85, 1.69 };                                      Test point is (2.5,-1.6) returns me a 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are pretty good implementations from the [iSurfer](http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html)

The two methods used in most cases (and the two I know of) are **crossing number** and **winding number**. **Both of them are not affected by the signs** of the polygon/point coordinates. So it must be a bug in your code.

For completeness I'm placing the code for a **crossing number test** which seems to be what you're trying to do in your code

```
// a Point is defined by its coordinates {int x, y;}

// isLeft(): tests if a point is Left|On|Right of an infinite line.
//    Input:  three points P0, P1, and P2
//    Return: >0 for P2 left of the line through P0 and P1
//            =0 for P2  on the line
//            <0 for P2  right of the line
//    See: Algorithm 1 "Area of Triangles and Polygons"
inline int isLeft( Point P0, Point P1, Point P2 )
{
    return ( (P1.x - P0.x) * (P2.y - P0.y) - (P2.x -  P0.x) * (P1.y - P0.y) );
}
//===================================================================

// cn_PnPoly(): crossing number test for a point in a polygon
//      Input:   P = a point,
//               V[] = vertex points of a polygon V[n+1] with V[n]=V[0]
//      Return:  0 = outside, 1 = inside
// This code is patterned after [Franklin, 2000]
int cn_PnPoly( Point P, Point* V, int n )
{
    int    cn = 0;    // the  crossing number counter

    // loop through all edges of the polygon
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {    // edge from V[i]  to V[i+1]
       if (((V[i].y <= P.y) && (V[i+1].y > P.y))     // an upward crossing
        || ((V[i].y > P.y) && (V[i+1].y <=  P.y))) { // a downward crossing
            // compute  the actual edge-ray intersect x-coordinate
            float vt = (float)(P.y  - V[i].y) / (V[i+1].y - V[i].y);
            if (P.x <  V[i].x + vt * (V[i+1].x - V[i].x)) // P.x < intersect
                 ++cn;   // a valid crossing of y=P.y right of P.x
        }
    }
    return (cn&1);    // 0 if even (out), and 1 if  odd (in)

}
//===================================================================
```

A special case that can arise with the crossing number number test, is when the **ray overlaps an edge** of the polygon. In that case it becomes somewhat fuzzy how to count intersections. That's why it's not the actual number of intersections we count, but **the number we crossed over semiplanes** defined by the ray.

The winding number test is more robust to this respect

Answer (score 0):

Note that if your polygon N and N+1 have the same y value then this test can fail computing vt. For example: determining if a point is inside an axis aligned square.

You need to deal with lines parallel on y